# Programs for 3D chemical molecules?

Tags: 3d, scientific-computing

I know there are lots of programs for drawing chemical molecules, but I cannot find the most advanced/suitable one for my needs:

- Drawing eye-catching 3D molecules with glassy colors.
- Having a large database of organic molecules to find a molecule by
  name.
- Any OS is acceptable, but it should not be a web-app
- I am not looking for "basic" free programs; price is not important if it is in a reasonable range

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for clarification of my question. I will keep in mind to add OS and price requirements in future questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Avogadro (https://avogadro.cc/) fits the bill.

- Free and open source
- Runs on Windows, Mac OS X, Linux
- Can build the molecule or import and tweak.
- Exports both raster graphics (like PNG) and vector graphics.
- Has POV-Ray support for eye-catching glassy colors.

[image: Example POV-Ray output]

Answer (score 1):

A linux based solution would be part of the KDE Education packages, Kalzium.

It uses the Avogadro2 libraries for its molecular editor, and can import pre-defined molecules as well.  But it also has a LOT of other chemistry related goodness, like chemical equation balancing, isotopes, basic info on each element, etc.

https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kdeedu/kalzium/index.html